# What's different calling a program from a terminal and from a window manager?

Tags: terminal, window-manager

For example I set up a combined keys of `i3` wm that calling `firefox`, what's different from it with calling `firefox` in a terminal?

Comment: `ls /proc/pid_of_firefox/fd -l` It doesn't get a terminal as stdin/stdout/stderr

Comment: I got this line: `8 00:18 0 -> /dev/pts/0`, the same as type `tty` in terminal, so I guess `firefox` was invoked from terminal and from wm wouldn't have that redirection.